# How to remove a newly installed kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I just installed this kernel manually kernel-3.10.26. But I am not able to remove it as it's not getting listed with yum or rpm.
How do I remove this kernel permanently??? 
I followed the following steps for installing this kernel:

- Untarred the tar.bz2 file downloaded from kernel.org
- added a value to EXTRAVERSION =  in the Makefile
- make gconfig  (to create the .config file)
- make -j4
- make modules_install
- make install
- reboot

OS Platform is Scientific Linux 6.5. I can boot into this kernel but I want to remove it now. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete `*3.10.26*` from `/boot`. This is what got `install`ed. Delete `/lib/modules/*3.10.36*` as well. This is what got `modules_install`ed. Run `update-grub` afterwards.

Note: before deleting, do an `echo` with the paths that I gave you to make sure they correspond to a single kernel and that is the kernel you want.

Comment: I just followed the steps.
But I couldn't run the update-grub.
There's no such command it says. I tried to install it with yum but still yum couldn't find the command update-grub.

Comment: Do you grub? Do you use lilo? That step is just to update your bootloader. If you don't knoe how to do it, find what bootloader you have and search online. In the worst case, don't do anything! On your next kernel update it should automatically be updated too.

Comment: I am using Scientific Linux 6.5 and it has Grub. I hope grub-update is not a feature specifically for grub2.
Anyways, I manually deleted the Grub entries for that kernel and it works fine.
But thanks for the info.
I'll check if the update could resolve it.

Comment: Yes, it could be from grub2. Glad you could resolve it, of course editing the files as you want is always an option. By the way, it's `update-grub` not `grub-update`.

Answer (score 2):

These steps are generally work for me, first make sure you boot into the desired version of the kernel you would want to remove:

1. rm /boot/{config-,initrd.img-,System.map-,vmlinuz-}`uname -r`
2. rm -rf /lib/modules/`uname -r`
3. sudo update-grub
4. reboot - this should not reboot you back to the previous version of the kernel

Comment: I just followed the steps.
But I couldn't run the update-grub.
There's no such command it says. I tried to install it with yum but still yum couldn't find the command update-grub.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me on Pop!_OS:

```sh
rm /lib/modules/<kernel-version>
cd /boot
mv vmlinuz.old vmlinuz
mv initrd.img.old initrd.img
sudo su
cd /boot/efi/EFI/Pop_OS-c505351a-07f6-4bcf-ab64-273c66fc0f5e 
mv initrd-previous.img initrd.img
mv vmlinuz-previous.img vmlinuz.img
rm /boot/efi/loader/entries/Pop_OS-previous.conf
```